# Use ArangoDB from C++

Tags: c++, rest, arangodb

Despite being written in C++, [ArangoDB](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb) does not provide a C++ driver, limiting the [choice of languages](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/) to Java, Go, C#, Node.js and Python.

Since my application is written in C++ I'm looking for ways to overcome this. Legacy docs, old SO questions and [blog posts](https://www.arangodb.com/2017/11/introduction-fuerte-arangodb-c-plus-plus-driver/) point to [Fuerte](https://github.com/arangodb/fuerte) which has long been discontinued.

- Is there an up to date C++ driver?
- If not, is using the http/REST API over something like [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) a sane choice? Are people doing this and is there a downside to it (limited features, difficulty in expressing built-in constructs like Graphs etc.)?

If the second option is suggested I'd appreciate any links to open source projects that use ArangoDB in this fashion - just to make the phrase "are people doing this" more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Fuerte is not discontinued, it has been integrated into the main ArangoDB repository: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/tree/devel/3rdParty/fuerte. Its status is described here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/3rdParty/README_maintainers.md#fuerte. However, documentation seems to be lacking and whether the blog post is still applicable is unclear.